# Searching text inside Html table on keyup event of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using asp.net mvc 5 with bootstrap.js with jquery to build a project.

In one of the page, there are some dynamic HTML that i am generating, which is a html table containing a list of employees.

I am trying to search the content with the below code.

it is called on the keyup event of the textbox.

jquery file refernced here:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Event registered at :

```
$(function(){
        $('#txtFilter').keyup(function(){
            FilterData();
        });
    });
```

Markup:

```
<div class="popHeader">
        Select Employee
    </div>
    <br>
    <span>Filter:<input id="txtFilter" type="text"></span>
    <br><br>
    <table id="tblSearch" class="table">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                EmployeeId
            </th>
            <th>
                Display Name
            </th>
            <th>
                CurrentUsername
            </th>
        </tr>
    <tr><td><a>Select</a></td><td>95961</td><td>Ankur</td><td>ankurda</td></tr><tr><td><a>Select</a></td><td>79761</td><td>Sameer </td><td>sameerba</td></tr><tr><td><a>Select</a></td><td>91060</td><td>Neeraj </td><td>Neerajsi</td></tr><tr><td><a>Select</a></td><td>83127</td><td>Pankaj </td><td>pankajpu</td></tr></tbody></table>


function FilterData()
    {
        debugger;
        var $rows = $('#tblSearch tr');


    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
}
```

whenever i type a single letter in the textbox i get this below error.

```
Error:Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined.
```

Not able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: How are you calling `FilterData()` You should pass a reference to `this`.

Comment: Error present somewhere else in your code.. since the provided code does not contains `toLowerCase` function call..?

Comment: i know there is no call, it comes with in jquery -file.... can you suggest.

Comment: show us how you are calling it from the jQuery file.

Comment: just added all the required source...